# HTTPClient Memory Issue

Tags: c#

I'm having some issues using the HttpClient class. When making multiple requests, my program's memory usage slowly creeps up. That wouldn't necessarily be an issue, but the problem is that when the process is done, the memory stays up there. Take this block of code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost").Result;
    string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

When running that bit of code, my program's memory creeps up from ~9MB to about 16MB, drops down to ~14.8MB, and then stays there. I feel like it's worth mentioning that the return result is ~50 bytes, so even if these 100 response strings were being kept in memory that doesn't account for the 6MB.

This becomes a huge issue when I'm executing thousands of requests - a 20,000 request set will leave my program consuming 600-700MB after the requests have all completed and the proper data has been exported and cleared.

I've looked through the heap with VS2015's diagnostic tools, and have found that the biggest offender is a List of PinnableBufferCaches. _SslStreams also make up quite a bit.

Why is this memory never freed? Even with such basic use of the HttpClient class, this issue can become debilitating. I can't seem to find any reasoning online, and feel like I'm just not looking for the right thing.

Edit: Even when calling Dispose on the client, or using a 'using' statement (see MickyD's answer below), the memory issue is exactly the same.

Comment: After doing the dispose, have you tried doing a `GC.Collect` as an experiment?  The garbage collector runs when there is memory pressure and will clean things up as needed.  It is possible that there is no pressure and thus the GC doesn't need to do any work

Comment: _"Even when calling Dispose ....the memory issue is exactly the same"_ - well, **not** calling it not a good idea either.  Sure .NET will tidy up after itself (within reason), but it's good practice

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` derives from `HttpMessageInvoker` which realises the `IDisposable` interface which means you need to place it in a `using()` block or call `Dispose()`.  .NET will eventually release the memory if you don't but it can lead to unwanted situations, particularly if you are using classes that deal with files.

MSDN has this to say on `IDisposable`:

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources. The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a managed object when that object is no longer used. However, it is not possible to predict when garbage collection will occur. Furthermore, the garbage collector has no knowledge of unmanaged resources such as window handles, or open files and streams. [Tell me more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)

Additionally, `HttpResponseMessage` is also marked as disposable.

Change:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost").Result;
    string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

...to:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())  //  <------ this gets disposed
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        using (var response = client.GetAsync("http://google.com").Result)  //  <--- and this
        {
            string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

### Alternatives

If the problem persists (you now indicate that you have already tried using `using()/Dispost`, I would recommend you use the memory diagnostic tools (**Analyse.Performance Profiler.Memory Usage**) in Visual Studio, it's entirely possible you memory problems have **nothing to do** with the code you posted.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had already tried 'using' and 'dispose'. The memory issue is exactly the same. I'll update the question.

Comment: The code block I provided is literally the only code inside the console application I put together to look into this. These are the objects using the most memory: http://puu.sh/tvamK/0a14f2d073.png (List<Object> contains 5 PinnableBufferCache objects)

Comment: I get that - however, I don't understand why simply calling these requests, and then disposing of them properly, is still leaving behind xMB of memory usage. This usage doesn't go away after forcing a garbage collect, and doesn't go away even when surpassing several hundreds of MB.

Comment: @Branden see the update.  It would appear the response is also **disposable**